# Editing data in todo list using javascript updating first list item and not others

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a todolist in javascript. I'm new in javascript and I'm encountering a problem from many days that  whenever i try to update my data in my todo list it always update the first list item data and doesn't update the data of list that i wanted to update it always updates the first list item. |Please solve this issue if anyone can i will be very thankful.

Here is my code:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const form = document.querySelector("#form");
  const input_text = document.querySelector("#text");
  const list_ele = document.querySelector(".tasks");
  const add = document.querySelector(".add-task");

  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    let text = input_text.value;

    let task = document.createElement("div");
    task.classList.add("task");

    let task_content = document.createElement("div");
    task_content.classList.add("content");
    task.appendChild(task_content);

    let output = document.createElement("input");
    output.classList.add("task-added")
    output.value = text;
    output.type = "text";
    output.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");

    task_content.appendChild(output);

    let actions = document.createElement("div");
    actions.classList.add("actions");
    task.appendChild(actions);

    let edit = document.createElement("button");
    edit.classList.add("edit");
    edit.innerHTML = "Edit";
    actions.appendChild(edit);

    let DELETE = document.createElement("button");
    DELETE.classList.add("delete");
    DELETE.innerHTML = "Delete";
    actions.appendChild(DELETE);
    if (add.value === "add-task")
      list_ele.appendChild(task);
    input_text.value = "";

    edit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      add.value = "Save";
      input_text.focus();
      input_text.value = output.value;
      add.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (add.value === "Save") {
          let targets = e.target;
          targets.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.value = input_text.value;
          add.value = "add-task";
          input_text.value = "";
        }
      });
    });
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.918);
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#form {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header h1 {
  color: orangered;
}

#form #text {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
}

#form .add-task {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: black;
  background-color: orangered;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
}

.tasks {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.task {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: orangered;
  gap: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
}

.task .content .task-added {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
}

.task .content .task-added:not(:read-only) {
  color: rgb(247, 2, 2);
}

.task .actions .edit {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: orangered;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
}

.task .actions {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
}

.task .actions .delete {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: orangered;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <h1>Todo-list</h1>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="text" required>
    <input type="submit" class="add-task" value="add-task">
  </form>

</header>
<section>
  <div class="tasks">
    <h2>Tasks</h2>
    <!--<div class="task">
            <div class="content">
                <input type="text" class="task-added" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit">
                <input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete">
            </div>
         </div>
         !-->
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the click event listener on the add/edit button when editing is finished. Check the comments in the updated code below:

```
edit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  add.value = "Save";
  input_text.focus();
  input_text.value = output.value;
  const onFinishHandler = () => { // <-------- put handler into variable
    if (add.value === "Save") {
      output.value = input_text.value; // <------------ simplify node access
      add.value = "add-task";
      input_text.value = "";
      add.removeEventListener('click', onFinishHandler) // <------ remove listener when done through variable
    }
  };
  add.addEventListener('click', onFinishHandler);
})
```